# Invoke functions regardless of their parameter types

Tags: function, go

Suppose I have a function which resides in the `fn` property of the following `Method` struct:

```
type Method struct {
  fn interface{}
}

var inst = &Method{func(a, b int) int {
  return a + b
}}
```

Now, I want to invoke this function with two arguments
**without** explicitly casting it to `func(int, int) int` like
so

```
a := 5
b := 6
fmt.Println(inst.fn(a, b))
```

How can I achieve this? Is there some generic solution for this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in Go without eventually using the reflect package.

Comment: That would also be ok if I could solve this problem using reflection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know is by using [`reflect.Value.Call`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Call):

```
type Method struct {
    fn interface{}
}

func (m Method) Call(args ...interface{}) {
    vs := make([]reflect.Value, len(args))
    for i := range args {
        vs[i] = reflect.ValueOf(args[i])
    }
    v := reflect.ValueOf(m.fn)
    v.Call(vs)
}

func main() {
    f := func(a, b int) {
        fmt.Println(a + b)
    }
    m := Method{f}
    m.Call(2, 3)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/JNtj2EMpu7.

Note: this will panic if fn is not a function or if the number or types of arguments are wrong. If you don't want that, you need to recheck all those conditions yourself.

Comment: Note, I strongly recommend you don't do that, in the end you will get more issues and hair-pulling bugs for a little syntactic sugar. And you probably can't do anything for return parameters... But that's a good catch (I was writing the same answer :P).

Comment: @Elwinar I agree about not using any of this unless there is no other way, but you can actually get the returned values, since `reflect.Value.Call` does return them.

Comment: Yes, but you would have to do a cast on the return value of `Method.Call`, which is not that practical in the end.

Comment: @Elwinar the moment you use something like this in Go, practicality becomes a very loose concept :)

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur reread the question. OP wants to do this "without explicitly casting it to func(int, int) int".

Comment: @Ainar-G: the moment you start doing this in Go is probably the moment you should be using something else :P

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, exactly what I was looking for. I don't want to use this as a measure to reduce code size or somehow write shorter code. I'm currently writing a small compiler (which does the type checking for me) and it generates go code which shall then invoke generated methods without the pain to cast everything accordingly (I'm doing this only for research purpose, therefore I don't mind weak performance).